# Extract segment of LineString between two points

Tags: openlayers-3

I know I can use `getCoordinateAt` to retrieve the coordinates of a point at a percentage along a LineString, but I need to extract a segement of a LineString between start and end fractions as a new LineString.

Any pointers as to how to achieve this with OpenLayers 3?

Thanks

Comment: How do you determine your start and end points?

Comment: Start and end points are expressed as percentage of the length of the line. I have some raw data that has items with known start/end distances along a path and I have a LineString representing the path.

Comment: I need to do something very similar.  I determine my start and end points as coordinates (they happen to always be on the line).  How to you extract the segment of the linestring resulting of what's between the points?